# Python context management and verbosity

Tags: python, logging

To facilitate testing code as I write it, I include verbosity in almost every module I write, as follows:

```
class MyObj(object):
    def __init__(arg0, kwarg0="default", verbosity=0):
        self.a0 = arg0
        self.k0 = kwarg0
        self.vb = verbosity

    def my_method(self):
        if verbosity > 2:
            print(f"{self} is doing a thing now...")
```

or

```
def my_func(arg0, arg1, verbosity=0):
    if verbosity > 2:
        print(f"doing something to {arg0} and {arg1}...")
        if verbosity > 5:                      # Added on later edit
            import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()       #  to clarify requirement
    do_somthing()
```

The executable scripts that import these will have collected (from the command line or elsewhere) a verbosity argument which gets passed all the way down the stack.

It's occurred to me to use a context manager so that I wouldn't have to initialize this variable at every level of the stack, something like having this in the driver script:

```
with args.verbosity as vb:
    my_func("x", "y")
```

Can I do that and then use vb in my_func without having to include it in the signature? Is there a better way to achieve this kind of control?

SUBSEQUENT EDIT: it's clear from the first answers—-thank you for those--that I need to check out the logging module, but in some cases I want to stop execution in the middle to inspect things at a particular stack level (see the `ipdb` code I am adding with this edit). Would you still recommend that I use logging? (I'm assuming there's a way to *get* the logging level if I felt *compelled* to occasionally litter my code with if statements like that one.)

Finally, I'm still interested in whether the context management solution would be expected to *work* (even if it's not the optimal solution).

Answer (score 1):

> To facilitate testing code as I write it, I include verbosity in almost every module I write ...

Don't litter your code with if-statements and prints for this kind of purpose. It makes the code messy, repetitive and less readable.

The use-case is exactly what stdlib [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) is for: you can *unconditionally* log events which describe what the program is doing, at various verbosity levels, and the messages will be displayed - or not - depending on the logging system's configuration.

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def my_func(arg0, arg1):
    log.info("doing something to %s and %s...", arg0, arg1)
    do_something()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(message)s")
    my_func(123, 456)
```

In the example above, the message will print because it is at level INFO which is above the verbosity level that I've configured logging with (DEBUG).  If you configure logging at level WARNING, then it won't display.

Generally the user will control the logging configuration settings (levels, formats, streams, files) via a config file, environment variables, or command-line arguments. It is up to the end-user to choose the specific logging configuration that meets their needs, as the developer you can just log events anytime. No need to worry about where the log events end up going to, or if they end up going anywhere at all.

Comment: Helpufl, thanks, I will explore. I'm assuming there's an easy way (like `-v 5` to control the logging level from the command line)?

Comment: @HaPsantran  You would usually do that by making the logging configuration call conditional on [parsed arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is levels of logging. For example, Python's builtin `logging` module has `error`, `warning`, `info`, and `debug` levels:

```py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()

logger.info('Normal message')
logger.debug('Message that only gets printed with high verbosity`)
```

Simply configure the logging level to debug, warn, etc., and you're basically done! Plus you get lots of native logging goodies.

Comment: Thanks; what sets verbosity in this example?